# html 5 draggable native unable to capture drop event

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have a div which in turn contains 10 draggable divs

```
<div id="doc">
  <div id"1" draggable="true"> lots of stuff here</div>
  <div id"2" draggable="true"> lots of stuff here</div>
  .........
</div>
```

In an html5 enabled browser I am able to drag drop these divs to change the order. As I inspect the DOM I can see that the whole divs has changed order as expected with all their contents intact.

so far not a single line of javascript.

When a drop has occurred I want to review the new order of the items and be able to react on that.

I have tried to use jquery

```
$('div').on('drop', function(){alert("test")});
```

cannot get it to work. I have tried many different ways of trying to capture this event that I am not able to remember them all.

I dont want to overcomplicate things. The native drag drop is doing exactly what I want. I could have a timer or on mouseup event listener that check the order of the items in the DOM but it frustrates me that I am unable to capture this seemingly simple and already working activity.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In this article probably you find the solution: [Posible Solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#drop)
You need to create a listener to de event "dragend" and in this function check the property dropEffect, if is none the drag was cancel, otherwise it specifies which operation perfomed.

If you want other solution, I sugest to use Jquery UI and it's methods draggable and dropable, this are very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this is still relevant. but @Vishkey gave me the idea to look for some `docs`.

I had the same issue. I could capture the `"drop"`, but all other `drap events` were just fine. seems that answers is hidden in the next paragraph:

> When the user releases the mouse, the drag and drop operation ends. If
>   the mouse was released over an element that is a valid drop target,
>   that is, one that cancelled the last dragenter or dragover event, then
>   the drop will be successful, and a drop event will fire at the target.
>   Otherwise, the drag operation is cancelled and no drop event is fired.

So after a close look we see that a drop event will fire only if the target is `valid drop target`. and if we look again (even more closer this time) we see that

> valid drop target,
>   that is, one that cancelled the last dragenter or dragover event

so the only thing one have to do in order to only dropping effect is to call `event.preventDefault();` on `dragpover` or on `dragenter`